# Get Filename from Byte Array

Tags: java, arrays, filenames, apache-tika

We can extract the mimetype from byte array, e.g., by using Apache Tika.

Is it possible to get Filename from Byte Array.

Comment: @Joey Honestly I haven't tried any thing. I searched Google but didn't find a way to solve it.

Comment: How did you get the byte array? Only that makes all the difference!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. You can take a guess at a mimetype from the content data itself, but the filename is not in there.

Answer (score 1):

The header field that you may be looking for is called [`Content-Disposition`](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2183.txt). If you're downloading an attachment, then there may be a file name in that field:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=abc.txt
```

But there's no guarantee that you'll have such a file name available. Also, this may only apply to HTTP and E-Mail content. From your question, it's not clear where your data's origin is...