# java how to get filename from binary data?

Tags: java

I'am reading a file through sockets, Is there a way that I can extract a file name, extension?

```
byte[] fileBytes; // filled byte[] array, how to extract info about file?
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a file name from a file's byte array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19912267/how-to-get-a-file-name-from-a-files-byte-array) (and also: [Get Filename from Byte Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884908/get-filename-from-byte-array))

Answer (score 2):

You can't get a filename from a binary data received from stream or socket, unless you know something about these bytes, for example

> First ten bytes represent filename in ASCII encoding.

If you have no such guarantees, no chance.